# Regular Expressions to select Intermediate values

Tags: regex

I am new to Regular Expressions, I was little confused to work in it. My link is

`<a href="https://vimeo.com/107828076">Embed</a>`

From this tag, if the inner value of `<href>` is "Embed" then the value coming immediate after to the .com must be selected.

I have already tried to this expression,

```
`<a(?:\s+href="(?:https://.*?/([^"]*))"\s*.*?)>(?:.*?(?i)Embed.*?)</a>`
```

Can I have some better expression to solve this issue?

Comment: What language / regex engine go you use?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a classic example of `positive lookahead`. What you have to do logically is look for `Embed`. If your requirement is only `Embed` then look for `>Embed<` and then capture whatever is followed by `.com`. Following regex achieves the same.

**Regex:** `<a.*\.com\/([^"]*)(?=.*\>Embed\<\/a>.*)`

**Flags used:** 
 - `g` if you are doing a global search.

**Explanation:**

- `(?=.*\>Embed\<.*)` looks for `Embed` **Only**.
- `<a.*\.com\/([^"]*)` captures everything after `.com` until the closing `"` only **if `<a>` is present**.

**Note:** `.com` will also be matched. But since you require only stuff after it you can use captured group `\1` or `$1`, whatever your regex flavor supports.

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pU5tF8/2)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but my issue is, if I am mentioning tag like this '<a href="https://vimeo.com/107828070"><a href="https://vimeo.com/107828075">Embed</a></a>' . I wanna get the inner href tag number.

Comment: @Balavinoth: Could you please clear the last point `if I am mentioning tag `.

Comment: @Balavinoth: I have updated my answer to match your requirements.